# Ruby on Rails - How do I use dashes instead of underscores in the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I ran the `rails generate controller Pages index sample_page` it created my two controllers.  I can see the page at `localhost:3000/sample_page`, but how do I change it to show dashes instead of underscores in the url ie: `localhost:3000/sample-page`

Rails doesn't like it when you create a controller with dashes, so I have to use underscore. What do I need to add to my routes.rb file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you should probably just create one controller for your pages.

To answer your question, you can do  some custom routes eg:

```
  match '/about-us' => 'pages#about'
  match '/contact-us' => 'pages#contact'
  match '/terms-and-conditions' => 'pages#terms'
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do you suggest I use one controller.  Isn't Pages the controller?  index and sample_page are the views?  How do I create one controller with multiple views?

Comment: I just needed to add `, :as => 'about'` to the end of each line.

Comment: Using "match" instead of "get" was causing an error in my situation, but other than that, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

use path in routing

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get :contact_us, path: "contact-us"
  end
end
```

Comment: I get an error (Unexpected :) when I put that in my routes.rb file.  Where exactly in the file should it go?  I tried inside my routes.draw do and outside of it.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake remove the colon(:) after get, 
It should be 
get :contact_us, path: "contact-us"